# how android determine the available themes for a project

Tags: android, themes

I have done a lot of googling but very surprised that I can not find ANY answer.  I am not sure for a specifc project what is the available themes for it.  It seems could be decided by :

The project target api level
The referenced library (implementation) in your gradle file
The Android Studio version,

> 

etc...

A follow up question is, if you have an activty in your library project that use a specific theme, is it possbile that the theme does not existing in the project that use the library.  If so, what is the right way to fix it.

Many thanks in advance.

Googled and searched in stackover flow, nothing at all

Comment: There are no such thing _available themes_ for a project unless you use a preconfigured one. Android studio creates a new project with a default material colors which you can alter later. Your project's _res_ directory must have the **values-night** and **values-not-night** directories in it. Which in turn the **night** corresponds to the dark theme, while **notnight** corresponds to light theme. You can configure these _*.xml_ files to create your own theme.

Comment: My understanding is that your statement is incorrrect.  For example, you can use "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar" , without putting anything in res directory,  because this is defined by the system.  If my understanding is incorrect, please let me know where I was wrong.  thanks.